# Histogram has only one bar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

My data--a 196,585-record numpy array extracted from a pandas dataframe--are being placed into a single bin by matplotlib.hist.  The data were originally integers, so I tried converting them to float as wel, as shown below, but they are still not being distributed among 10 bins.

Interestingly, a small sub-sample (using df.sample(0.00x)) of the integer data are successfully distributed.

Any suggestions on where I may be erring in data preparation or use of matplotlib's histogram function would be appreciated.

[image: histogram output]

```
x = df[(df['UNIT']=='X')].OPP_VALUE.values
num_bins = 10
n, bins, patches = plt.hist((x[(x>0)]).astype(float), num_bins, normed=False, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: try using `log=True` - your sample contains very few large values which skew the distribution. You may have to think about removing them.

Comment: Yup. Looks like you need to zoom in all the way in. Can you print the output of `print(n); print(bins);`.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, so much so that log=True even doesn't work:  **print(bins)**
[  1.00000000e+00   3.00000000e+09   6.00000000e+09   9.00000000e+09
   1.20000000e+10   1.50000000e+10   1.80000000e+10   2.10000000e+10
   2.40000000e+10   2.70000000e+10   3.00000000e+10]  **print(n)**
[  1.86114000e+05   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]

Answer (score 5):

Most likely what is happening is that the number of data points with x > 0.5 is very small but you do have some outliers that forces the hist function to pick the scale it does. Try removing all values > 0.5 (or 1 if you do not want to convert to float) and then plot again.

Comment: Im also facing this issue, could you explian a littile elaborately,, I am plotting after removing outliers using z score and I am getting this

Answer (score -1):

you should modify number of bins, for exam

```
number_of_bins = 200
bin_cutoffs = np.linspace(np.percentile(x,0), np.percentile(x,99),number_of_bins)
```